Regridding two different curvilinear grids onto a common rectilinear grid with R
I have numerical model outputs (in this example, ocean surface temperature) from two different models that cover different spatial domains. Both sets of outputs are on their own curvilinear grid (which has been a learning curve!). The larger domain model extent incorporates that of the smaller domain model. I am trying to create a raster (rectilinear) grid where the outputs (data) from the two models are seamlessly combined, so that the data from the smaller domain model (which also has a higher native resolution) replaces/over-writes the data from the larger domain (and lower resolution) model. I think I have managed to do this with a convoluted approach, using the stars R package and the final step accomplished with gdalwarp in a bash terminal (see screenshot of the final raster loaded in QGIS). However, my questions are:

Can the two curvilinear grids be warped/transformed onto the rectilinear grid within R (without having to warp them to rectilinear grids and saving those to implement the final step with gdalwarp)?

Is there a better way to approach this problem? I might have gone down the wrong rabbit hole.


I have provided a GitLab repository with the below R code and the files needed to run the code, which demonstrates my approach. I don't have the skills to build minimal example curvilinear grids and apologies for the lengthy script.
I should acknowledge code and (limited) understanding from pages that include:
https://r-spatial.org/book/07-Introsf.html
https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars4.html#curvilinear-grids
https://www.mattreusswig.com/post/use-stars-to-visualize-curvilinear-netcdf-rasters/
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390148/handle-curvilinear-rotated-grid-netcdf-file-in-r
#####################################################################################
##
## Purpose of script:
## develop a reproducible example of trying to add data from a larger-domain woesII
## (1/12th degree resolution) curvilinear grid, as well as a smaller-domain woesIII
## (1/36th degree resolution) curvilinear grid to a common (and higher resolution)
## rectilinear grid, so that the woesIII data replace the woesII data where the former
## exist (and the data from the two original grids are seemless in the output).
##
#####################################################################################
### packages & functions

require(stars)

#####################################################################################
### settings

### filenames & directories (note files are read from and saved to an 'outputs' folder, you may need to replace throughout if you did not create the same directory)

grd_fl <- "outputs/receiving_grid_2km.tif" 

wIII_fl <- "outputs/temp_woesIII_singleday.nc"

wII_fl <- "outputs/temp_woesII_singleday.nc"

varname <- "temp"

#####################################################################################
### load data

### load the new grid file
grd <- read_stars(grd_fl)
grd

### load the two (curvilinear) model output grids:
## woesII data
wII <- stars::read_ncdf(wII_fl, var = varname)
wII # not recognised as a curvilinear grid (unlike when I opened the original model files), so incorporate the below to tell it:  
coords_wII  <- stars::read_ncdf(wII_fl, var = c("lon_rho", "lat_rho")) #
## Convert the lat lon coordinates into matrices with the same dimensions as the raster data.
x_wII = matrix(coords_wII[[1]], nrow(coords_wII[[1]]), ncol(coords_wII[[1]]))
y_wII = matrix(coords_wII[[2]], nrow(coords_wII[[2]]), ncol(coords_wII[[2]]))
## tell stars this is a curvilinear grid with coords from x & y
wII <- st_as_stars(wII, curvilinear = list(longitude = x_wII, latitude = y_wII))
wII # now it recognises it as a curvilinear grid

## woesIII data
wIII <- stars::read_ncdf(wIII_fl, var = varname)
wIII # not recognised as a curvilinear grid (unlike when I opened the original model files), so incorporate the below to tell it:
coords_wIII  <- stars::read_ncdf(wIII_fl, var = c("lon_rho", "lat_rho")) #
## Convert the lat lon coordinates into matrices with the same dimensions as the raster data.
x_wIII = matrix(coords_wIII[[1]], nrow(coords_wIII[[1]]), ncol(coords_wIII[[1]]))
y_wIII = matrix(coords_wIII[[2]], nrow(coords_wIII[[2]]), ncol(coords_wIII[[2]]))
## tell stars this is a curvilinear grid with coords from x & y
wIII <- st_as_stars(wIII, curvilinear = list(longitude = x_wIII, latitude = y_wIII))
wIII # now it recognises it as a curvilinear grid

## in order to recognise whether the below methods are working, I'm temporarily going to alter the data of wIII (so that clear discontinuities will be visible where the two datasets meet in the final product, avoiding any uncertainty of whether the output is a combination of the two datasets).
wIII <- wIII*1.5
wIII # 50% higher temperatures

#####################################################################################
### try adding them to the new grd

newgrd <- st_warp(wII, grd)
image(newgrd) # seems to have worked to add the larger extent woesII grid
newgrd <- st_warp(wIII, newgrd) # also tried with , options="overwrite=F"
image(newgrd) # inserts the wIII grid but doesn't keep the surrounding data from wII, replacing those with NA
## is there a way to insert the wIII data without losing the wII data (in areas outside the extent of the wIII data)?

### trying with gdal_utils; note this was guessing; I'm not familiar with gdal_utils()
aa <- gdal_utils(util = "warp", source = c(wII, wIII), destination = grd) # I tried various 'along' arguments, but didn't manage to get it right

#####################################################################################
### I did seemingly manage to warp the two grids onto one higher resolution grid with 'gdalwarp' (implemented from a bash terminal as shown below); but to do that, the two curvilinear grids need to be saved as rectilinear raster grids first, as far as I can make out:
### so, warping to rectilinear grids and saving those outputs as follows:

## create rectilinear grids with same number of gridcells as the curvilinear grids
grdII <- st_bbox(wII) |>
  st_as_sfc() |>
  st_transform('OGC:CRS84') |>
  st_bbox() |>
  st_as_stars(nx = dim(wII)["longitude"], ny = dim(wII)["latitude"])

grdIII <- st_bbox(wIII) |>
  st_as_sfc() |>
  st_transform('OGC:CRS84') |>
  st_bbox() |>
  st_as_stars(nx = dim(wIII)["longitude"], ny = dim(wIII)["latitude"])

## and warp the data from the curvilinear grids onto the rectilinear grids
wII_rectilinear <- st_warp(wII, grdII)
wIII_rectilinear <- st_warp(wIII, grdIII)

## save the files:

write_stars(wII_rectilinear, "outputs/temp_woesII_singleday_rectilinear.tif")

write_stars(wIII_rectilinear, "outputs/temp_woesIIIx1.5_singleday_rectilinear.tif")


and then running the below two lines in a bash terminal (will throw errors in R) after navigating to the outputs folder
cp receiving_grid_2km.tif woesII_2km_grid.tif # copy the receiving grid as it gets over-written in the next line  
gdalwarp temp_woesII_singleday_rectilinear.tif temp_woesIIIx1.5_singleday_rectilinear.tif woesII_2km_grid.tif  


It has taken some time to noodle through all that is presented. Until we get to gdalwarp we (I) don't have a sense of what resolution should be between woesII 0.08318916, 0.071844) and woesIIx1.5 (0.02773656, 0.02291187), though we have the opportunity to set in stars  st_warp curvilinear presumably cellsize=c(. Still checking on gdal_utility as applied to above and success or failure. I've saved this ? as a primer on curvilinear grids, assembling as it does many useful inputs. Write a no rabbit answer perhaps.

terra:::from_stars, type conversion. st_warp( cellsize=c( 0.08318916, 0.071844)) works. Just some notes.

Thank you for taking the time to work through my question, @Chris (and apologies for slow response from myself, I was away for a few days). I'm uncertain from your comments whether you're wanting me to do or try anything further yet (I think not). The resolutions used for grdII and grdIII are not critical for this example, I simply used the same number of gridcells as were in the curvilinear grids, though I'd use higher resolutions in my final implementation.

Actually, I'm suggesting you write an answer on the 'proper' approach (without rabbit holes) and accept it. ?(s) 1) should grdII <- st_bbox(wII |> warning on Euclidian distance on geodetic coordinates be concerning warp.R and does it come up in a strictly gdalwarp context (i.e. are we passing sufficient parameters - beyond threshold in st_warp or are further parameters 'exposed'?) It is unfortunate that the files here don't contain crs nor wkt, but given the Euclid/geodetic are the results impaired? Thinking how to pose this at gdal.dev.

As it will help others similarly burdened pre-process and move on to accurate analysis.

Ok, thanks for clarifying. I will play around with it a bit more and see if I can streamline the example and try to write the CRS to the daily netcdf files I saved for the purpose. I must admit, I hadn't paid much attention to the warnings yet, as I was just trying to get a process working. Will look at those more carefully too.

I have wanted to ask the source of the original satellite temp data nc as tucked away in there as variables should have been something, some group of variables that likely could have been coaxed toward a wkt and thus inform proj and friends.

The original files can be found here: http://dap.saeon.ac.za/thredds/catalog/SAEON.EGAGASINI/2019.Penven/DAILY_MEANS/catalog.html
I was using the 1_36_degree (named wIII in above script) and the 1_12_degree (named wII above) outputs.
They are regional ocean model outputs and the files contain daily averages for many variables on a variety of grids and most variables have 60 depth levels. You can see more here if interested: https://www.myroms.org/wiki/Numerical_Solution_Technique

I had saved a single day and depth level to the netcdf files loaded in the above script to try and simplify the example. I'm happy to share that script with you if you'd like. It uses the ncdf4 package to load the files, extract the single-day and depth-level data and then write a new netcdf file with those.

Yikes. Or Yikes!, but then I think, 'there's an r pkg for that' angstroms. The choice of a pkg name here I think is joining angst with roms, a pun of sorts for those willing to entertain the edge of madness, though might obscure the pkg intent to deal with roms. mdsumner actively ferrets out edge cases at gdal.dev. The approach proposed in angstroms, rather to elide the curvilinear messiness until absolutely necessary may be worth our reviewing, or compare your extracting to it.

Thanks for pointing out that package, Chris. I can't believe I didn't find it previously. Might have saved me a lot of pain. I'll look into it and report back.

Useful to look through github angstroms /inst directory as there are many .rmd files that were likely meant to be vignettes, but are perhaps a hassle to maintain through cran pkg checks, so not published as such. Still figuring that out...and back to painting the ceiling.
